# current position in on map android

Tags: android, dictionary, position

I am building an app in which there is an activity to search games and players and when this activity starts a map also starts.My problem is that the map does not shows current position unless and untill we click on the show my location button..What I want to do is that on start of activity my map will point to my current position as in Google Maps on our android devices along with a pointer or marker ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(curlat, curlong); // LatLng  current location

gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My location"));
```